# Forge viewer THREE js font loader

Tags: three.js, autodesk-forge

I'm working with forge viewer. Currently, I want to add a mesh along with text placed on it. But I can't load the font from THREE js. THREE.js version in forge viewer doesn't have THREE.FontLoader or THREE.Font. How can I add text on mesh in forge viewer?

This is my code

```
const textGeometry = new (THREE as any).TextGeometry(area.title, {
          font: new (THREE as any).Font(FontJson),
          size: 10,
          height: 1,
          curveSegments: 12,
          bevelEnabled: false,
        });

const textMesh = new THREE.Mesh(
          textGeometry,
          new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffffff })
        );

mesh.add(textMesh);

this.viewer.impl.addOverlay(AreaOverlay, mesh);
```

Answer (score 1):

There's handy material showing users how to add text to the APS Viewer. One of the resources can be found on the main APS blog post that has an article on how to add labels to the Viewer: https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/how-do-you-add-labels-forge-viewer

This blog will guide you on how to use meshes and add them to a scene in the Viewer.